# sequence spaces as subsets of each other

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces

Given the sequence spaces $\ell^p$ that are defined as:

$$\ell^p = \left\{a = (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^p < \infty\right\}$$

for $\infty > p ≥ 1$, how can it be shown that $\ell^1 \subset \ell^2$?

Thanks in advance for any help! It came to my mind that there are sequences like $(\frac{1}{n})$, that's infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but when we consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$, we have a convergent series for $p > 1$. So I'd say it's a real subset. But I don't know how to show that the other direction is indeed valid, that each sequence of $\ell^1$ also lies in $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a_n)\in\ell_1$, then it is bounded. There is a constant $M>0$ such that $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n$. Then for any $p>1$ we have
$$
\sum|a_n|^p\le M^{p-1}\sum|a_n|<\infty,
$$
proving that $\ell^1\subset\ell^p$.